# Resolving git conflicts - Result page shows lines of unknown origin?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I am currently trying to resolve conflicts between two branches. IntelliJ's "Merge Revisions" window shows three panels: "local changes", "result" and "changes from server".

I would like to know how IntelliJ generates the "result" panel as I am seeing conflicting lines where both the left and the right panels have the exact same code but the center panel shows something different.

Update:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: please put screenshot of the problem statement.

Comment: the link to the screenshot dont work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
--*--X--*--*--* <- local
      \
       \-*--*--* <- remote
```

When a merge triggers a conflict, `git` provides the id of the commit `X` -- the point when the two branches forked, and which git uses as a "starting point" for the merge.

Most 3-way diffs viewer simply start by bluntly displaying the version of the file in `X`.

You then have to integrate all the modifications you wish to keep in this central pane, and save, to indicate to git that you "solved the conflict".

---

Does this match what you see ?

Is the "version in the middle" a common version, from which both your remote and local branch forked ?

Comment: I see what is going on now. It seems someone made identical changes after the fork in both branches (don't ask me about their motivations). The question now is whether IntelliJ/git can compare the two branches without the fork point version to find these lines? Or can that only be resolved manually?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. From the branches popup, select the branch that you want to compare with the branch you are currently on, and choose Compare from the submenu. Then you can see a list of all files that diverged in the two branches and display diff for them. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-git-integration.html for details

Comment: Are you answering my comment from the other answer? If so, this is not a more automatic way of resolving these kinds of conflicts, it's still manual.